# Build @Url.Action string

Tags: asp.net-mvc, string, razor

I want to build a url string `'@Url.Action("Homepage","Home")'`, but I am using a parameter.I tried something like this:  `'@Url.Action('+parameter+'"Home")'`,but it's not working.Thanks in advance

Comment: `@Url.Action("Homepage","Home", new {parameter1=value1, parameter2=value2})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what your Controller method looks like, and the parameters that it is taking in you can do this:

**Controller:**

```
// Controller Name is SOAnswer

public ActionResult Index(string example1, string example2)
{
    // logic here
}
```

**View/Action:**

```
@Url.Action("Index", "SOAnswer", new { example1 = "test1", example2 = "test2"}
```

Using this for research:

[MSDN Article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper.Action%28System.String,System.String,System.Object%29)

**Syntax:**

```
public virtual string Action(
    string actionName,
    string controllerName,
    object routeValues
)
```

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: I want something like this :var action="SOAnswer"; @Url.Action("Home",action);but it's not working

Comment: @AlexandruMihai ohh you are putting the controller in a variable called action.. and you are doing this in the view? Can I ask what is the benefit of doing this?

Comment: sorry..it is my mistake..i want to say @url.action(action,"Home")

Comment: @AlexandruMihai well that is incorrect syntax for the `url.action` method... you first need the `actionName`, so maybe try `var action = "Homepage"` then you could try `@url.action(action, "Home")`

Comment: glad you figured it out!